# Localization of custom class set in storyboard doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I added `MyTextField`, which inherits `UITextField`.

And,set the textField's custom class set in storyboard to `MyTextField`.

I localised the textFields's placeholder,but it doesn't work.

If I empty custom class, it works fine.

I can set by code, but could you tell me better choice?

Comment: I have the same problem. have you found any solution?

Comment: I noticed this doesn't work with table view cells with a preset style. If I changed the cell to a custom style and build the cell from scratch, it will localize my custom label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug (unless someone can point me out to a link where such a behavior is detailed as normal by Apple).

What I did was to keep the localizations in the localized storyboard files and manually load them at runtime from there, using `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` :

```
MyTextField* myTextField = <find your textField>;
myTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"PyC-mJ-2Mz.placeholder", @"storyboardName", nil);
```

The name of the localized string can be found by searching in the localized files for the storyboard. It is a very ugly and manual way of patching the behavior, but at least this way, when (if?) the bug is fixed, all you have to do is to remove that line.